# Could not resolve all files for configuration :compileClasspath

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have a problem with building a gradle java project when I run the command`./gradlew build` I get the error in the screenshot below. I have spent several hours trying all the ways I could find here on SO but none of them worked (so don't mark this as duplicate) all the answers seem to be about proxies but I'm not using any proxies in the gradle.properties file and I could also access the urls from the logs in my browser and they work just fine.
Thank you in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAFEE.png

Here's my build.gradle
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaoLG.png

NOTE: As you can see I'm running gradle on my phone yes I know that's not the best idea but I know for sure this problem is not related to this.

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle file ?

Comment: @xiaomi I edited my question

Comment: oh wait, are you building a library or are you just building a small java program ?

Comment: @xiaomi It is a java library

Comment: sorry, I don't know from where the error could come :/

Comment: @xiaomi its okay, thanks for your time

Comment: The most likely explanation _is_ that you need to specify an HTTP proxy. There's a good chance that your browser is configured with an HTTP proxy or using some other mechanism, hence why you can access the URL. I've experienced the same issue in the past. A good test is whether `curl` can access that URL.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook thanks for your reply, a 'curl -Is' to one of the urls returned 200 code.
Can you please tell me about proxies how do I use them in gradle and how can I find one

Comment: Wikipedia on proxy servers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: One other diagnostic test you can try is to use https://github.com/krickert/java-wget to access the URLs. Alternatively, if you have Groovy installed, you can use `new URL(...).bytes` from the Groovy console. The aim is to see whether plain Java code can access the URL. If it can, then the issue is probably not a proxy.